# Install an ASP.NET application on a UNC path, do you think it's possible?

Tags: asp.net

I am planning to deploy an ASP.NET application to a UNC path and create a virtual directory that points to the UNC path.

For example the location of the ASP.NET application would be:

```
\\server01\myFirstApplication\
```

Instead of:

```
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myFirstApplication
```

Do you see if we have any complication with this?

Comment: Interesting question.  I've never thought of doing that... Please come back and update with how it turns out.  I'd like to hear of any challenges you have, and how you address them.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem so long as your application pool account has the necessary permissions on the network share. Depending on the location of the share with respect to the IIS server, this may require that you use a domain account for the application pool.

Comment: Could run into problems with impersonation if the site uses Windows authentication.  Delegation trusts would need to be set up for this.

Comment: @squillman: Very true. This is what I intended to convey by "Depending on the location of the share with respect to the IIS server..." Thanks for providing providing additional clarification.

Comment: Yep, it does go a bit beyond just using a domain account in the app pool, though.

Comment: @squillman: Agreed; however, the OP gave no hint of which authentication protocol or identity strategy the application used. I chose to err on the side of simplicity. I would suggest posting your own answer when you have material of value to add.